# Are "when/whenever/where/wherever possible" synonyms?

Tags: difference

This [Macmillan dictionary](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/when-whenever-where-wherever-possible) suggests that the *when/whenever/where/wherever possible* are synonyms:

> when or where you have an opportunity to do something.
>   *I relax with a good book whenever possible.*

However, I've seen this answer (it seems from a native speaker) on this [forum.wordreference.com](https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/where-possible-when-possible.1127514/) post:

> It seems obvious to me that "when" refers to time and "where" to place.
>
> Call me when possible. (= call when you have time)
>
> Walk where possible. (= walk wherever you can or are allowed to)
>
> In the above exercise the obvious answer should be "when" because it
>   refers to time, unless I'm missing something.

It suggests that they are different. I'm confused. I've also seen this example from the Potter book:

> Always brought people in alive where possible.

In this case, can we put: 
*Always brought people in alive when/whenever/wherever possible.*? Would they mean the same thing?

Comment: Very interesting. Have never give any considerations before. You are genius.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**where** can refer to context or situation.

> Where there's an indication of domestic abuse, the clinician must inform the authorities.

That phrase is synonymous with "In situations where..."

Consider the word **situation** itself, which comes into English from medieval Latin and medieval French.  By that time it is figurative, since it doesn't really refer to a place (Medieval Latin *situare*) but to a set of circumstances.  Oops, now you must consider the word **circumstances**, whose meaning is itself founded on a spatial metaphor.

Comment: So "when/whenever/wherever possible" are not synonyms? Can we replace where with when/wherever/whenever here?

Comment: In my example, **when** and **whenever** could be used too.  **Whenever** would connote a bit more obligation or urgency.  But there are times when **whenever** cannot be used in place of **when**:  *Wake me whenever it's 2PM*.  It's not helpful to think of such words as synonyms.  *Call me when you get there* means call me upon your arrival there. *Call me whenever you get there* means call me  upon your arrival whatever time that happens to be, if you can't say now what that time will be.

Comment: I'm particularly interested in the usage of the phrases "When possible", "where possible", "wherever possible" and "whatever possible".

Comment: *When possible* and *where possible* are interchangeable as are  *whenever possible* and *wherever possible*.