# What does "Took a bit of me with him" mean here?

Tags: meaning-in-context

> “Why, yes…there was Rosier,” said Karkaroff hurriedly. “Evan Rosier.”
>
> “Rosier is dead,” said Crouch. “He was caught shortly after you were
>   too. He preferred to fight rather than come quietly and was killed in
>   the struggle.”
>
> “**Took a bit of me with him**, though,” whispered Moody to Harry's right.
>   Harry looked around at him once more, and saw him **indicating the large
>   chunk out of his nose** to Dumbledore.

I figure "Took a bit of me with him" probably mean *Moody sacrificed something while dealing with Rosier*. According to the later context, it probably refers to the large chunk on his nose(I don't understand "out of nose" here either). How should we understand it in this context?

-- From *Harry Potter and the Goblet of Fire*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Took a bit of me with him"  drops the subject, "he", as is typical in conversation.

He took a small piece of me with him.

"with him" means "in his possession (as he sought to flee)".  *Better take your umbrella with you when you leave for work this morning.*   That is probably figurative; it doesn't necessarily mean that Rosier had the chunk of Moody's flesh on his person. So you are correct, Moody lost or sacrificed a piece of himself.

With **though** Moody concedes that Rosier was killed, yes, but not before he was able to remove a chunk of flesh from Moody's nose.

P.S. In the phrase *the large chunk **out of** his nose*, the words **out of** can be understood to mean "missing from".

> There was his birthday cake on the table, but with a large slice already out of it.

That means there was a slice missing from the cake.

Comment: Your interpretation of "Took a bit of me with him" is completely different from what I originally thought. What I thought was that *it cost a bit of me while I fought with him*. I understood 'take' as the sense of 'cost'. And your explanation about "out of" here helps a lot!

Comment: @dan Gruesome to think you were imagining a "large chunk" of  Moody exiting a nostril :)

Comment: Yeah, that's kind of embarrassing. Stupid mistakes are often made by second language learners though. Can you also do me a favor and take a look at my another question: https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/190723/are-when-whenever-where-wherever-possible-synonyms

Comment: @dan plenty of stupid mistakes are made in one's first language too ;)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, Rosier in the struggle removed a part of Moody's nose.

The chunk came **out of** Moody's nose.

Comment: Thanks! What might "the chunk out of his nose" refer to? Will it be some substitute for the part that has been removed by Rosier?

Comment: It means a piece of nose was cut off from Moody's nose by Rosier.